# Bluetooth HM-10 in central mode bonding with another bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth HM-10 configured in central mode. I have successfully connected it to another bluetooth device (a hexiwear bluetooth wearable). The problem now is that the hexiwear requires me to provide a 6 digit pin before it will bond with my HM-10.

Would anyone know the AT command that I could use to send the 6 digit pin from the HM-10 to the hexiwear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The manual for the HM-10 can be found [here](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/Modules/IM130614001_Serial_Port_BLE_Module_Master_Slave_HM-10/DS_IM130614001_Serial_Port_BLE_Module_Master_Slave_HM-10.pdf).

Page 11 has the AT command you are interested in: `AT+PIN`:

```
AT+PIN123456
OK+Set:123456
```

By default the PIN is `000000`.

(The manual is quite vague about the role of that command, so I assume since it is the only reference to PIN codes that it does what you require).

Comment: Thanks for the response. APIN command sets the PIN for the HM-10. My HM-10 is running central mode and I am trying to connect to a hexiwear (www.hexiwear.com) in peripheral mode. I am able to connect the hexiwear by sending AT+CON<address>. After successful connection, the hexiwear pops up a 6 digit pin that I am required to now send from the HM-10. This is where I am stuck because I do not know if there's a AT command that lets me send a pin from central to peripheral.

Comment: Have you tried setting both devices to use the same pin?

Comment: Not yet, this requires me to hack my peripheral device because the pin it sends is a random number. But I will hack it and report back again soon. Thank you.